# Creating select list from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am making select list from database table everything works fine only issue is in option value if the value consist of two words like "New York" it only returns "New". Here is the code

```
<?  $country=intval($_GET['country']);

include('connect-db.php');

$query="SELECT CityName FROM cities WHERE CountryId='$country'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="city">
<option value="">Select City</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$row['CityName']?>><?=$row['CityName']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Right below your query put $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);  echo  $row['CityName']; just so we can test this

Comment: You haven't used the quotation marks around that value <option value="<?=$row['CityName']?>"><?=$row['CityName']?></option>

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="<?=$row['CityName']?>"><?=$row['CityName']?></option>
```

The " " .

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to surrond the value in "", the HTML code thinks the York part is just another attribute of the option tag, so:

```
<option value="<?=$row['CityName']?>"><?=$row['CityName']?></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the "" while giving the values. if you look at the html created for the select box by your code is something like

```
<option value="new" york>new york</option>
```

correct solution is given below, just included the quotation while giving value of option tag.

```
<?  $country=intval($_GET['country']);

include('connect-db.php');

$query="SELECT CityName FROM cities WHERE CountryId='$country'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="city">
<option value="">Select City</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value="<?=$row['CityName']?>"><?=$row['CityName']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Suggestion: use FireBug with mozilla firefox to see you html and debug your javascript or jquery code, that will help you finding the real problem in code.

Comment: As you got correct solution you can marks the best answer as correct and you can also give upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "" for the value of value same as you write HTML tag.